# Is it possible to get the diff for just one file using the github API?

Tags: git, github, github-api

Using the github API's [compare endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits), I can request the unified diff between two commits:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.3.diff' \
'https://api.github.com/repos/danvk/dygraphs/compare/01275da4...335011f'
```

Using the git command line tool, I can filter that diff to just a single file:

```
git diff 01275da4..335011f dygraph.js
```

Is there any way to do this with the github API? I realize that I can filter down to just that diff as a post-processing step, but this could run into API restrictions if the diff contains a large file in addition to a small file.

Comment: That's not possible currently.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done with the current version (3) of the GitHub API.

You will have to deal with the mix of files until they add a parameter (much like how Listing method has the `path` flag) that allows you to specify what file to limit the view/compare commit method.